# How can we jump back in to the constructor body from it's function try handler?

Tags: c++

**Disclaimer** : This question is totally theoretical and full of imagination and dreams, so readers discretion is required :)

So I was reading about exception objects, and I read in IBM C++ reference that :

> In a function try block’s handler, you cannot have a jump into the
>   body of a constructor or destructor.

I know why one shouldn't try to jump back in to the constructor's body... blah blah blah... but I was more curious about if it wasn't abomination, how could I jump back in to the constructor's body.

1. Use `return` statement
2. `goto` statement

or author is directing to some another method ?

Comment: give an example for "jump back into contructor body" because I can't think if any.

Comment: Just use an initialize function you call from the constructors body and from the catch block.

Comment: Any link on the document you are refering to ?

Comment: I don't think "jump[ing] into the body of a constructor or destructor" is allowed *anywhere*. (That's a seriously badly written text you've found, BTW.)

Comment: @molbdnilo It's not allowed I know, if one was supposed to do it, how would one do I wonder. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is remotly close to this scenario is `Async/Await`

`Async-Await` keywords comes from the C# programing language and probably be a part of the standard starting from C++17.
Visual studio 2015 RTM already supports this extremly important feature.

`Async/Await` goes as follows , if `Z()` is an asynchronos function, when this flow happens

`X() calls-> Y() calls-> await Z()`

`Z()` will be lauched, the code flow *jumps back to `X()`* without destroying **`Y()` and `Z()`**. when `Z()` finishes, you can asynchronosly jump back to 
`Y() calls-> await Z()` with the result of `Z()` and continue from there as the function never returned/destroyed.

This is a *coroutine* implemntation.

why am I talking about it? because you can wrap the iside of async function with `try/catch` blocks inside a constructor.

A C++17 Example:

```
struct ContentManager{
   std::string m_data; 

   Awaitable<std::string> getDataFromTheNet(){/**/}
   std::future<void> initializeData(){
        try{
           m_data = await getDataFromTheNet();
        }catch(...){/* handle */}
   }

   ContentManager(){
       initializeData();
   }
};
```

In this example, you de-facto jump from a try block back into the constructor who called it in the first place.

Why isn't it cool?
because when `ContentManager` constructor finished, I , as a developer, thinks that the object is initialized, but this is clearly not the case!

Answer (score 0):

[`setjmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/setjmp) and [`longjmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/longjmp) let you jump from anywhere to a specific place in the code, potentially in a constructor. You should not do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdnoreturn.h>
#include <iostream>

struct Jumpable
{
    jmp_buf jump_buffer;
    Jumpable()
    {
        // Don't do it at home
        std::cout << setjmp(jump_buffer) << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Jumpable jump;
    longjmp(jump.jump_buffer, 1);
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
bash: line 7:   608 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/005d70726696a74b)

Comment: Read the statement , in a function TRY BLOCK .

Comment: You can jump from a `catch` ;)

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL And this answer the question "I['d like to know] how could I jump back in to the constructor's body. "

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieve by a simpler way as indicated below :
Example is based on the fact that if current scope is not able to catch exception then exception will be propagate to the outer scope .Now ,imagine if you are calling a function from constructor and that function doesn't handle the exception it has just thrown then that exception will be propagated to c'tor .

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class A {
 public:
 void fun()
 {
    throw 2;   
 }
 A(){
  try {

      fun();

  }

  catch(int e)
  {
      std::cout<<"\n constructor try block\n ";


 }}

};

int main()
{
   A a1;
   return 0; 
}
```

output : constructor try block

Comment: The code basically show how to swallow a exception from within constructor, in no way it shows what I had asked :( . Even I know what I asked won't work in real code though, yet a written example would help.